# Regex in javascrtip

Tags: javascript, regex

My regular expression is to find the first occurrence of vowel in a string.

```js
function findIndex(str) {
    var regex = /[aeiou]/gi
    var vowelIndice = str.indexOf(str.match(regex)[0]);
    console.log(vowelIndice);
    }

    findIndex("consonant");
```

I am not able to understand after `str.match(regex)` ,why we are indexing with [0] ?

Comment: str.match returns all matches in str as an array...so you take the first occurence and find it's index

Comment: You could also make proper use of the code-formatting option.